# what process killers does linux have?

Tags: linux, kill, out-of-memory

Some of my jobs are getting killed by the os for some reason.  I need to investigate why this is happening.  The jobs that I run don't show any error messages in their own logs, which probably indicates os killed them.  Nobody else has access to the server.  I'm aware of OOM killer, are there any other process killers? Where would I find logs for these things?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean the OS killed them.  A program might "segmentation fault" or have a bug (crash) or exceed `ulimit` restrictions (heap is a good one, as is too many processes for a java threaded app) or exceed JVM defined limits (for a java program) or die for many other reasons; none of these may necessarily log output in application logs.

Comment: the job is a python scripts, so I highly doubt it's a seg fault.  it takes about 24gb of memory.

Comment: In case of a python script, any unhandled exception would do. There's not nearly enough information in the question to go beyond guessing.

Comment: can you at least get the return code from a parent process?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I don't overwrite or suppress any python exceptions.

Comment: It was in fact OOM, I found the messages in var/log.  I guess at some point the memory usage spiked up and OOM took care of it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller this script was ran from the shell.  So, I guess the shell is the parent.  Just for future reference, how would I get the return code from the parent of a dead process?

Comment: @mss: If the parent process is a (reasonable) shell, *immediately after the command has terminated* you can do `echo $?` to get the return code.  If you run any other commands, they will clobber the value of the `$?` variable and you will lose this information.

Comment: As you can see from the answer, this is a good question. Could perhaps be phrased better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

oom is currently the only thing that kills automatically.

> dmesg

and */var/log/messages* should show oom kills.

If the process can handle that signal, it could log at least the kill.

Normally memory hogs get killed. Perhaps more swap space can help you, if the memory is only getting allocated but is not really needed.

Else: Get more RAM.

Comment: Correction: "oom [killer] is currently the only thing that kills automatically **external to the process**". As @StephenHarris mentions, it's entirely possible for a program to terminate itself for a variety of reasons that might not show up in a system or application log (e.g. `SIGSEGV`).

Answer (score 9):

Coming to mind:

- getting a `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS` for invalid memory access
- `SIGILL` for invalid instructions
- `SIGFPE` when doing an invalid arithmetic operation like division by 0
- `SIGXCPU` or `SIGXFSZ` if the process exceeds some limits
- `SIGHUP` for disconnected terminals and some other situations
- `SIGPIPE` when trying to write to a closed pipe or socket